# Free module generated by a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $G$ be an abelian group, $R$ be a commutative ring (with unit), then I want something that I'd like to call "free module generated by group $G$ over ring $R$".

let $M_G$ be the set of formal expressions $r_1\cdot g_1+r_2\cdot g_2+...+r_n\cdot g_n$, where all $r_j\in R$, $g_j\in G$. Define an equivalence relation on $M_G$ by these rules:

1. $+$ is commutative.
2. if $r+r'=r''$ in $R$, then $\forall g \in G, r''\cdot g \sim r\cdot g+r'\cdot g$
3. if $g+g'=g''$ in $G$, then $\forall r \in R, r\cdot g'' \sim r\cdot g+r\cdot g'$

Let $\overline{M_G}$ be the quotient $M_G/\sim$, then $\overline{M_G}$ is a module over $R$ by $$r\cdot \overline{\sum_j r_j\cdot g_j} = \overline{\sum_j (rr_j)\cdot g_j}$$

$G$ is embedded in $\overline{M_G}$ by the inclusion map $i: G \rightarrow \overline{M_G}$, which is a group monomorphism:

$$i(g) = \overline{1\cdot g}$$

And there's a universal property: any $M$ module over $R$, such that there exists a group homomorphism $i': G \rightarrow M$, then there exists a unique module homomorphism $\pi : \overline{M_G} \rightarrow M$ such that $\pi\circ i = i'$

I just want to find a name for this construction. I can't find any name for this. It looks kind of like a tensor product, kind of like a free module generated by a set, but it's neither. Do you know what would be the name for this construction? And where can I find more information on this construction? I feel like it should have some significance but I can't find any reference on this construction by Google.

Comment: This is called the *group ring*, written as $R[G]$. Instead of your quotient construction, you can consider the set of maps $G\to R$ with finite support (equipped with the obvious addition and multiplication)

Comment: @Hagen That was my first thought too, but in the third point addition in the group becomes addition in the module.

Comment: In general, free objects come with certain universal properties (e.g. free group on a set, free algebra on a vector space). Do you have one such property that your free module should have?

Comment: I think I found the universal property I'm thinking about: $\forall M$ module over $R$, such that there exists a group homomorphism $i': G \rightarrow M$, then there exists a unique module homomorphism $\pi : \overline{M_G} \rightarrow M$ such that $\pi\circ i = i'$

Comment: "Free" is not the right word, but it's an understandable guess at what the right term should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction looks to me like the tensor product of abelian groups $R\otimes_{\Bbb Z}G$. The usual construction of the tensor product is pretty much what you have written, if you replace the dots by $\otimes$.

Moreover it has the universal property you mentioned in the comments : given a group homomorphism $i':G\to M$, you can define
$$\pi : M_G \to M:\sum_jr_j\otimes g_j\mapsto \sum_jr_ji'(g_j)\in M.$$
Then you can check that $\pi$ is a $R$-module homomorphism, and you have $\pi(i(g))=\pi(1\otimes g)=1i'(g)=i'(g)$ for all $g\in G$, so $\pi\circ i=i'$; and if $\phi: M_G \to M$ is another $R$-module homomorphism with that property, then
$$\phi\left(\sum_j r_j\otimes g_j\right)=\phi\left(\sum_jr_j\cdot (1\otimes g_j)\right)=\sum_jr_j\cdot \phi(i(g_j))=\sum_jr_j\cdot i'(g_j),$$hence $\phi=\pi$.

It's a special case of extension of scalars, or [induced module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings), with one of the rings equal to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: It means that we take the tensor product of $\Bbb Z$-modules (i.e. abelian groups). Thus the tensor product must be $\Bbb Z$-bilinear, thus for all $m\in \Bbb Z$, we must have $(m\cdot r)\otimes g=m\cdot (r\otimes g)=r\otimes (m\cdot g)$.